# Is Ashura the actual creator of the "Rasengan"?

Tags: naruto

So as you can see in the fillers, that when Ashura is helping out the other villagers, he is using a jutsu just like the Rasengan.

1. Is this the Rasengan we know and love, or is this a different jutsu for say a wind release?
2. If it is indeed the Rasengan, then does this mean that Ashura is the original creator, and not Minato Namikaze?
3. If the second one is true, this could mean that Minato has some relations with the Ōtsutsuki?

Comment: I meant Minato BTW but both sayings are correct.

Comment: You can always hit the edit link below your post to fix things rather than comment.  It will make it much easier to read (and then people don't need to filter through the comments to figure out what you meant.)

Comment: @Becuzz I Didn't Know, im new to this website but thank you for telling me this

Answer (score 6):

It depends on what you consider canon. Almost all of the Ashura and Indra and even Kaguya backstory stuff was anime only filler. The manga has almost none of that. Thus, in the manga, there was no mention of Ashura ever using Rasengan, or pretty much any specific jutsu for that matter. Indra's eyes barely resembled a sharingan, and Hagoromo was never known to not have the Rinnegan. So in that regard, Ashura isn't the creator, its just anime only filler. They likely chose things like the Rasengan and Sasuke's Mangekyou and put them on the two brothers to try and make it all seem more like destiny or something, symbolism that things are repeating themselves. Its pretty low quality story and a plot hole because Madara doesn't have the same pattern even though he was also an Indra trans-migrant. The story wasn't about destiny, but instead about how Naruto used the power he was given to change things, when the world finally was ready for it.

If you consider anime filler canon, then indeed he is the original creator, but like another answer here points out, he didn't pass it on. Minato most definitely developed the Rasengan on his own. In that regard, they both are the creators, Minato just rediscovered it.

Answer (score 1):

Nobody even knew who Indra and Ashura were before Hagoromo told his story.Indra are Ashura are ancient history.Not even Hashirama/Madara knew about them.

Yes,Ashura was the creator of Rasengan.In fact,he had already created an advanced version of it-multiple Rasengans.Howeved his jutsu was probably not passed down to the next generation,it was forgotten.

Minato re-discovered the Rasengan and essentially,became it's present creator.Rasengan is actually a ball of chakra-you could add a Wind Release to it and make it Wind Style and stronger as well.The reason why it's so powerful is because it's pure chakra,unlike other jutsus where you have to convert your chakra to the desired "style",like the Fire ball jutsu.

Clearly,Minato has no relations with the Otsutsuki clan.

Answer (score 0):

You're already answered it yourself. It's a filler.

Aside from that, I don't think that counted as Rasengan, since it wasn't really a perfect compressed sphere, but a round unstable mass of wind release chakra. So you could say in this filler, Asura used a proto/pseudo/imperfect Wind Release: Rasengan. Also, the Rasengan was **explicitly stated** to be based off of the Tailed Beast Ball, which automatically makes it structurally and functionally different from whatever Wind Release technique Asura was using in this episode. It looks like a Rasengan, but it's not. Just like Chidori and Raikiri are similar to whatever technique the 3rd Raikage used.

There is no relation between Minato and the Ōtsutsuki Clan.

Answer (score 0):

...Ashura created the Rasengan it was never passed down because nobody had the skill at the time to recreate it since the concept of chakra was new to the world Indra had his sharigan during his battle with Ashura...I’m pretty sure that story was Canon it explained things in the main story line unlike side missions used for filler

Comment: Can you provide citations or any additional details?

Answer (score -2):

Just like GK A said ashra's chakra wind release is similar to the rasengan just like chidori and raikiri are similar to the 3rd raikage thrust of hell lighting style jutsu plus it possible that ashra created the rasengan but due to the fact that he didn't teach anyone how to do it and no one border to try copy it may be because it was he's jutsu like his thing.

so eventually as time pass by his jutsu was forgotten and minato namikaze rediscover it due to inspiration of a tail beast's most powerful jutsu known as the tail beast ball but again it's highly possible to say that ashra didn't create the rasengan but the birth state or form of it just like how the rasengan is the birth state or form of the rasen-shuriken and again ashra's rasengan like jutsu was a projectile type jutsu while minato rasengan is a contact type jutsu.

so technically they both got there inspiration from the tail beast ball but had different law for human possession like how ashra's rasengan like jutsu copied the projectile feature of the tail beast ball but was a chakra ball like bubble with five rasengan balls rotating in it and how minato's rasengan copied the oneness feature of the tail beast ball but was a contact type jutsu not a projectile like the tail beast ball so clearly due to my idea on who created the rasengan one can say that ashra did not create the rasengan, minato did just like how u can say that minato did not create the rasen-shuriken, naruto did.

clearly one can call ashra's rasengan like jutsu the rasen-hado or ashra's rasengan like boruto vanishing rasengan a rasengan but a projectile type jutsu just like his ashra's kurama mode![image][image][image][image]